# How can I add a new semantics on esprima parser?

Tags: esprima

I want to use `esprima` parser to parse mongo shell scripts. Basically mongo shell is using javascript syntax but with some additional commands. For example, `use test` is one statement on mongo shell to switch to the `test` database. If I put this string to `esprima.parseScript` I will get an exception because this is not a valid javascript code. I wonder what the easiest way for me to add some new semantics like `use test` on `esprima` parser.

Answer (score 0):

Both Esprima and acorn has many bugs and doesn't support latest ecmascript.  Have you looked at something like the Cherow parser? https://github.com/cherow/cherow